# need a space from navigation on top in a mvc project

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I make a side bar in the left side of a page by using of panel and  and on the top of page I have a navigation. now when I run the program panel header shows below the navigation.
I have made a stylesheet

```
 top-margin-page{
padding-top:8cm;                
 }
```

I put the panel in a column of a row and row is inside a container. I use my style sheet as a class attribute for row and I did not get the result then I put it for container and did not get the result. also I added my stlesheet at top of page as

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/myStyles")
```

in top of page

Answer (score 1):

```
body {    
    margin-top: 8cm !important;
}
```

Comment: I used margin-top for body in bootstrap and it appears unkown so I used margin:3cm,0,0,0,0 and i did not get the result

Answer (score 1):

just a quick check, your css should be:

```
.top-margin-page{
    padding-top:8cm;                
}
```

note the `.`

then you can use it like:

```
<div class="top-margin-page">...</div>
```